# File Management Module for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, file-management, role-base-authorization

The requirement is to develop a file management system with role based access. Suppose, there will be three types of users, User A, User B and User C. User C is under User B, User B is under User A. So, the files and directories assigned to User C, should be accessible by User B and A. Files and directories assigned to User B should be accessible by User A and not by User C.

Drupal 6 has amodule, named WebFM which deals all the requirements very fine. Unfortunately, there is not Drupal 7 version of WebFM. I need all the features a WebFM module has, like drag and drop, ajax uploading etc.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [filedepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) module which behave like webfm module for Drupal 6.

The module is full featured Document Management module that has a google docs like feel.

Comment: I tried filedepot module in Drupal 7 it's working fine. But it doesn't support user specific upload option. Once "User A" uploads "file1" it's visible to all authenticated users. How to avoid this on filedepot module?